# Reading com port using asio library. The checksum does not match. Python->c++

Tags: c++, serial-port, boost-asio, com-port

I have a small project in C++. Reading the COM port. I have code that opens a COM port and reads values from it. When compressing the buffer during checksum check with the generated checksum the values do not match.

It means that

```
 if (checksum != generated_checksum) {
     return;
 }
```

is fulfilled.

This is my code.

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;

// mocking question code
struct {
    void info(std::string const& msg) const {
        static auto const start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        auto ts = (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start);
        if (ts > 1s)
            std::cout << std::setw(6) << ts / 1.s << "s  " << msg << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << std::setw(6) << ts / 1ms << "ms " << msg << std::endl;
    }
} static g_logger;
// end mocks

struct COM {
    asio::thread_pool m_ioc{1};
    asio::serial_port m_port{m_ioc};
    std::atomic_int   m_Data = 0;

    std::weak_ptr<void> m_readoperation; // only when read operation active

    void ReadLoop(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned char>> buffer = {}) {
        if (!buffer) {
            assert(m_readoperation.expired()); // do not post overlapping read operations
            buffer          = std::make_shared<std::vector<unsigned char>>();
            m_readoperation = buffer;
        }

        asio::async_read(
            m_port, asio::dynamic_buffer(*buffer), asio::transfer_at_least(1),
            [this, buffer](boost::system::error_code ec, size_t /*length*/) {
                if (!ec) {
                    try {
                        // Directly process binary data from buffer here.
                        size_t length = buffer->size();
                        m_Data.store(length);

                        // Example processing based on your description
                        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
                            if (i + 2 < buffer->size() && (*buffer)[i] == 170 && (*buffer)[i + 1] == 170) {
                                size_t packetLength = (*buffer)[i + 2];
                                if (packetLength < 4 || packetLength >= 170) {
                                    continue; // Invalid packet length, move to next byte.
                                }
                                if (i + 2 + packetLength <= buffer->size()) {
                                    // Assume parse_packet processes a packet starting from a specific index
                                    // and uses packetLength to determine the end.
                                    // This function needs to be adapted to accept a start index and length,
                                    // or you need to create a sub-vector to pass to it.
                                    parse_packet({buffer->begin() + i, buffer->begin() + i + packetLength});
                                    i += packetLength - 1; // Move to the end of the packet.
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // Clear buffer after processing, or handle remaining bytes as needed.
                        buffer->clear();
                        // Continue reading into the same buffer for new data.
                        ReadLoop(buffer);
                    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
                        g_logger.info("Error processing received data: " + std::string(e.what()));
                    }
                } else {
                    // Handle read errors.
                    g_logger.info("ReadLoop error: " + ec.message());
                }
            });
    }

    void parse_packet(std::vector<unsigned char> const& data) {
        if (data.size() < 4)
            return; // Minimal packet length

        int generated_checksum = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size() - 1; ++i) { // Exclude the last byte, which is the checksum
            generated_checksum += data[i];
        }
        generated_checksum = 255 - (generated_checksum % 256);

        int checksum = data.back(); // Assume the last byte is the checksum
        g_logger.info("Checksum: " + std::to_string(checksum) +
                      ", Generated checksum: " + std::to_string(generated_checksum));
        if (checksum != generated_checksum) {
            g_logger.info("Checksum failed ");
            return; // Checksum mismatch
        }

        // Iterate through packet data, excluding the checksum
        size_t i = 0;
        while (i < data.size() - 1) {
            unsigned char data_type = data[i++];
            switch (data_type) {
            case 1: { // Battery level
                //..rest of code..//
                //
            }
            }
        }
    }

    void initialize(bool enable = true) {
        sleep_for(100ms);

        m_port.open("COM5");

        // Configure serial port settings
        using P = asio::serial_port;
        m_port.set_option(P::baud_rate(115200));
        m_port.set_option(P::character_size(8));
        m_port.set_option(P::parity(P::parity::none));
        m_port.set_option(P::stop_bits(P::stop_bits::one));
        m_port.set_option(P::flow_control(P::flow_control::none));

        g_logger.info("Connected");

        setEnabled(enable);
    }

    void setEnabled(bool enable) {
        if (enable == !m_readoperation.expired())
            return; // nothing to do

        if (!enable)
            m_port.cancel(); // cancels read operation (asio::error::operation_aborted)
        else
            ReadLoop();
    }

    void terminate() {
        setEnabled(false);
        g_logger.info("Bye!");
    }
};

// demo code
int main() {
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
    g_logger.info("Demo start");
    COM g_com;

    g_com.initialize(false);

    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        sleep_for(3.5s);
        g_logger.info("Main thread observed atomic int value: " + to_string(g_com.m_Data));

        bool enable = i % 2; // enable if odd, disable if even
        g_logger.info(enable ? "Enabling read operation" : "Disabling read operation");
        g_com.setEnabled(i % 2);
    }

    g_com.terminate();
}
```

This is output

```
Checksum: 128, Generated checksum: 167
Checksum failed 
Checksum: 128, Generated checksum: 167
Checksum failed 
Checksum: 128, Generated checksum: 167
Checksum failed 
Checksum: 128, Generated checksum: 167
Checksum failed
```

The checksum does not change at all and neither does the generated checksum.

In Python, checksums look like this:

```
91 , 91
109 , 109
114 , 114
83 , 83
38 , 38
25 , 25
45 , 45
57 , 57
76 , 76
82 , 82
83 , 83
84 , 84
67 , 67
69 , 69
100 , 100
```

I can't find the cause of the checksum error

Python Code:

```py
def receive_byte():
    global CurrentPosition
    if CurrentPosition >= len(ReceivedString):
        return 0
    result = ReceivedString[CurrentPosition]
    CurrentPosition += 1
    return result

def skip_byte():
    global CurrentPosition
    CurrentPosition += 1

def drop_parsing():
    global UnparsedRemainingString, ReceivedString, CurrentPosition
    UnparsedRemainingString = b""
    if CurrentPosition > 3:
        UnparsedRemainingString = ReceivedString[CurrentPosition-3:]
    if len(UnparsedRemainingString) > 128:
        UnparsedRemainingString = b""
    ReceivedString = b""

def parse_packet(length):
    global Raw_count, needSave, SaveFile
    generated_checksum = 0
    payload_data = [0 for _ in range(171)]  # Initializing payloadData array
    for i in range(length):
        payload_data[i] = receive_byte()
        generated_checksum += payload_data[i]
    generated_checksum = 255 - generated_checksum % 256
    checksum = receive_byte()
    print(checksum,",", generated_checksum)
    if checksum != generated_checksum:
        return
    
    if length < 4:
        return

    i = 0
    while i < length - 1:
        data_type = payload_data[i]
        i += 1
        if data_type == 1:  # battery level
            battery_level = payload_data[i]
            i += 1
            print(f"battery_level: {battery_level}") 
 //....//
def read_data_from_serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=9600):
    global ReceivedString, CurrentPosition, UnparsedRemainingString
    ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate, timeout=1)
    while True:
        data = ser.read(ser.in_waiting or 1)
        if data:
            ReceivedString = UnparsedRemainingString + data
            CurrentPosition = 0
            while CurrentPosition < len(ReceivedString) - 2:
                if receive_byte() == 170 and receive_byte() == 170:
                    length = receive_byte()
                    if length < 4 or length >= 170:
                        continue
                    if CurrentPosition + length > len(ReceivedString):
                        drop_parsing()
                        break
                    else:
                        parse_packet(length)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    read_data_from_serial('COM6', 115200)  # Example usage
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do note how I made your sample code more self-contained. It's actually less work **not** to cripple your question code. You were in luck that I remembered your previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse engineering from the C++ code, your message structure is:

\xaa \xaa LEN DATA[LEN]

When matching "\xaa\xaa" at `i` you pass only the buffer range `[i, i+LEN)` to `parser_packet`. That's 3 bytes short. This fixes it for me:

```
asio::async_read(
    m_port, asio::dynamic_buffer(*pbuf), asio::transfer_at_least(1),
    [this, pbuf](boost::system::error_code ec, size_t /*length*/) {
        if (!ec) {
            try {
                // Directly process binary data from buffer here.
                auto&        buffer = *pbuf;
                size_t const length = buffer.size();
                m_Data.store(length);

                // message \xaa \xaa LEN DATA[LEN]

                // Example processing based on your description
                if (length > 2)
                    for (size_t i = 0; i < length - 2; ++i) {
                        if (buffer[i] == 170 && buffer[i + 1] == 170) {
                            size_t packetLength = buffer[i + 2];
                            if (packetLength < 4 || packetLength >= 170) {
                                continue; // Invalid packet length, move to next byte.
                            }
                            if (i + 3 + packetLength <= buffer.size()) {
                                parse_packet({buffer.begin() + i + 3, packetLength});
                                i += packetLength - 1; // Move to the end of the packet.
                            }
                        }
                    }

                // Clear buffer after processing, or handle remaining bytes as needed.
                buffer.clear();
                // Continue reading into the same buffer for new data.
                ReadLoop(pbuf);
            } catch (const std::exception& e) {
                g_logger.info("Error processing received data: " + std::string(e.what()));
            }
        } else {
            // Handle read errors.
            g_logger.info("ReadLoop error: " + ec.message());
        }
    });
```

That is to say, when testing with a payload of `"\xaa\xaa\x04abc\xd9"` it decodes back to 217 (0xd9) correctly.

I also suggest using `span` to pass to `parse_packet` instead of copying the data:

```
void parse_packet(std::span<uint8_t const> data) {
```

### Live Demo

**Live On Coliru**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using namespace std::string_literals;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;

// mocking question code
struct {
    void info(std::string const& msg) const {
        static auto const start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        auto ts = (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start);
        if (ts > 1s)
            std::cout << std::setw(6) << ts / 1.s << "s  " << msg << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << std::setw(6) << ts / 1ms << "ms " << msg << std::endl;
    }
} static g_logger;
// end mocks

struct COM {
    asio::thread_pool m_ioc{1};
    asio::serial_port m_port{m_ioc};
    std::atomic_int   m_Data = 0;

    std::weak_ptr<void> m_readoperation; // only when read operation active

    ~COM() { m_ioc.join(); }

    void ReadLoop(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned char>> pbuf = {}) {
        g_logger.info("Readloop" + (pbuf ? " with buffer"s : ""));
        if (!pbuf) {
            assert(m_readoperation.expired()); // do not post overlapping read operations
            pbuf          = std::make_shared<std::vector<unsigned char>>();
            m_readoperation = pbuf;
        }

        asio::async_read(
            m_port, asio::dynamic_buffer(*pbuf), asio::transfer_at_least(1),
            [this, pbuf](boost::system::error_code ec, size_t /*length*/) {
                if (!ec) {
                    try {
                        // Directly process binary data from buffer here.
                        auto&        buffer = *pbuf;
                        size_t const length = buffer.size();
                        m_Data.store(length);

                        // message \xaa \xaa LEN DATA[LEN]

                        // Example processing based on your description
                        if (length > 2)
                            for (size_t i = 0; i < length - 2; ++i) {
                                if (buffer[i] == 170 && buffer[i + 1] == 170) {
                                    size_t packetLength = buffer[i + 2];
                                    if (packetLength < 4 || packetLength >= 170) {
                                        continue; // Invalid packet length, move to next byte.
                                    }
                                    if (i + 3 + packetLength <= buffer.size()) {
                                        parse_packet({buffer.begin() + i + 3, packetLength});
                                        i += packetLength - 1; // Move to the end of the packet.
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        // Clear buffer after processing, or handle remaining bytes as needed.
                        buffer.clear();
                        // Continue reading into the same buffer for new data.
                        ReadLoop(pbuf);
                    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
                        g_logger.info("Error processing received data: " + std::string(e.what()));
                    }
                } else {
                    // Handle read errors.
                    g_logger.info("ReadLoop error: " + ec.message());
                }
            });
    }

    void parse_packet(std::span<uint8_t const> data) {
        if (data.size() < 4)
            return; // Minimal packet length

        int generated_checksum = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size() - 1; ++i) { // Exclude the last byte, which is the checksum
            generated_checksum += data[i];
        }
        generated_checksum = 255 - (generated_checksum % 256);

        int checksum = data.back(); // Assume the last byte is the checksum
        g_logger.info("Checksum: " + std::to_string(checksum) +
                      ", Generated checksum: " + std::to_string(generated_checksum));
        if (checksum != generated_checksum) {
            g_logger.info("Checksum failed ");
            return; // Checksum mismatch
        }

        // Iterate through packet data, excluding the checksum
        size_t i = 0;
        while (i < data.size() - 1) {
            unsigned char data_type = data[i++];
            switch (data_type) {
            case 1: { // Battery level
                //..rest of code..//
                //
            }
            }
        }
    }

    void initialize(bool enable = true) {
        sleep_for(100ms);

        m_port.open("COM5");

        // Configure serial port settings
        using P = asio::serial_port;
        m_port.set_option(P::baud_rate(115200));
        m_port.set_option(P::character_size(8));
        m_port.set_option(P::parity(P::parity::none));
        m_port.set_option(P::stop_bits(P::stop_bits::one));
        m_port.set_option(P::flow_control(P::flow_control::none));

        g_logger.info("Connected");

        setEnabled(enable);
    }

    void setEnabled(bool enable) {
        if (enable == !m_readoperation.expired())
            return; // nothing to do

        if (!enable)
            m_port.cancel(); // cancels read operation (asio::error::operation_aborted)
        else
            ReadLoop();
    }

    void terminate() {
        setEnabled(false);
        g_logger.info("Bye!");
    }
};

// demo code
int main() {
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
    g_logger.info("Demo start");
    COM g_com;

    g_com.initialize();
    // g_com.terminate();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Also, I think the `buffer.clear()` is a bug. You want to drop only the message processed, not all following data. I'll leave that as an exercise

Comment: Everything works, but unfortunately I lose a lot of data.
Is using asio::async_read a good solution? The Python code processes a lot of data per second, and in my C++ code only 1/second to a maximum of 3-4/sec.
I clear the buffer after parse_data like this: buffer.erase(buffer.begin(), buffer.begin() + i + 3 + len); 

and I checked the buffer is not overflowing.

Comment: I don't trust you did it correctly. I think your code is unnecessarily complicated. If you ask a new question with your current code, sample data that demonstrates you lose data out will be an easy fix. Conceptually you want to separate message detection and the receive loop. That will simplify your code.